# HTML5 tag (main) not recognized in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, html5

I have the following HTML5 document:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='css/styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="img/logo.png"/>
        <div class="logo-text">some text</div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section>
            <div class="message-text">
                <p>text1</p>
                <div class="small-text">
                    <p>text2</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>item 1</li>
                        <li>item 2</li>
                        <li>item 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

When opening this file in Eclipse I get the following error message: `Unknown tag (main)`

The version of Eclipse is as follows:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1), Build id: 20140925-1800

Comment: The duplication mark is wrong, there's no answer on the linked question, just read the comments there. This question uses the correct DOCTYPE and deactivating validators because of one unknown element is no solution. A correct solution would be to tell how one can get Eclipse to either ignore the "main" warning alone or make "main" known to Eclipse.